# How do I plot points in 3D space from a N x 3 matrix?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

How would I plot in 3D space (`plot3()` I presume) from a matrix containing `N` rows of coordinates where column 1 is `x`, column 2 is `y` and column 3 is `z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your matrix is in `X`, it's as simple as:

```
plot3(X(:,1), X(:,2), X(:,3), 'b.');
```

`plot3` takes in three arguments as a base.  The first argument are the `x` coordinates, the second are the `y` coordinates and the third are the `z` coordinates.  Because you have all three coordinates conveniently in a matrix and each are in separate columns, you just have to pluck out each coordinate and put that into `plot3`.  I'm also assuming that the points are discrete and you don't want to join any of the points together, so the fourth argument denotes both the colour of the points as well as the style of the points.  Here, I've made them blue and single dots.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be `scatter3`.

```
X = rand(30,3);
scatter3(X(:,1), X(:,2), X(:,3), 'b.');
```